# Exceedance (1-cdf) plot using seaborn and pandas

Tags: pandas, seaborn

Assume a dataframe `df` with a single column (say `latency`, i.e. a uni-variate sample). The exceedance function is calculated and plotted as follows:

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values('latency')
samples = len(sorted_df)
exceedance = [1-(x/samples) for x in range(1, samples + 1)]
ax.plot(df['latency'], exceedance, 'o')
```

Is there a simpler/elegant way to calculate and plot exceedance function of a univariate sample using seaborn (may be `distplot`)? I recently learnt using `seaborn`'s `distplot` function, but I can only plot the cdf as follows:

```
sns.distplot(df['latency'], hist=False, kde_kws={'cumulative':True})
```

I'm specifically interested in `seaborn` because I plan to use this function along with `Seaborn.FacetGrid` to get an exceedance plot for several factors.

Comment: The above code is only 4 lines long. So, yes you may make it more efficient by using numpy, `exceedance = 1.-np.arange(1.,len(df) + 1.)/len(df)`, but else I don't see the need to use seaborn (as this is not built in). Note that kde is not the same, as it does not plot the actual data, so you also need to decide what you actually want. Also note that you may use `plt.plot` in a FacetGrid.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks for your input. With some experimentation, I realized I could use `plt.plot` along with `FacetGrid`. I'll write my solution and mark it as the answer.

Comment: Since the question is not very clear, I doubt that a solution to that unclear question makes much sense. But of course you may edit the question to specifically ask for the problem you then later also answer. However I have the feeling that if the problem was to use plt.plot for a FacetGrid, there are already some questions and answers about that, so no need to create another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you asked for a more elegant way, the following saves you two lines of code and is faster.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_exceedance(data, **kwargs):
    df = data.sort_values()
    exceedance = 1.-np.arange(1.,len(df) + 1.)/len(df)
    plt.plot(sorted_df, exceedance, **kwargs)

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='factorA',col='factorB',hue='factorC')
g.map(plot_exceedance, 'latency')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no predefined API/paramaters to calculate exceedance. So, I had to use the code listed above. But considering that I was specifically interested in getting an exceedance plot of several factors and that I could use `plt.plot` along with `seaborn.FacetGrid`, the following piece of code worked.

```
def plot_exceedance(data, **kwargs):
    sorted_df = data.sort_values()
    samples = len(sorted_df)
    exceedance = [1-(x/samples) for x in range(1, samples + 1)]
    ax=plt.gca()
    ax.plot(sorted_df, exceedance, **kwargs)

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='factorA',col='factorB',hue='factorC')
g.map(plot_exceedance, 'latency')
```

where `factorA`, `factorB` and `factorC` are additional columns in `df`.